# How to translate this group name in mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates, semantic-mediawiki

I installed `Extension:CommentStreams` of mediawiki and it adds an user group called `staff`.
How can I translate this group name in mediawiki? Any other group names are translated by default as I chose my language in `LocalSettings.php` but this group name is not translated. How possible?

Comment: ??? "staff" is not a Comment stream group. See https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CommentStreams#Comment_moderation

Answer (score 1):

Group names are translated via the messages `group-XXX`, `group-XXX-member` and `grouppage-XXX`. See [docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights#Creating_a_new_group_and_assigning_permissions_to_it). CommentStreams does not use a `staff` group, though, as other commenters have noted.